Live Activity not workin on Simulator
Live Activity isn't working on the iOS 17.5 Simulator but works on a physical device. When I first close the app, it updates once, but then nothing updates anymore.
Supports Live Activities - YES
Signing & Capabilities
. Push notification
. Background modes
. Background fetch
. Remote notification
. Background processing
struct OrderLiveActivityView: View {
    @State private var activity: Activity<OrderWidgetAttributes>? = nil
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = 0.33
    @State var activityTimer: Timer?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                start()
            } label: {
                Text("Start")
                    .bold()
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button {
                removeLiveActivity()
            } label: {
                Text("Remove")
                    .bold()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var progressBarView: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<4) { index in
                    Circle()
                        .fill(index <= Int(progress * 2) ? Color.green : Color.gray)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("\(index + 1)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.caption)
                        )
                    if index < 3 {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            
            ZStack {
                // Points above the progress bar
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<4) { index in
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                        
                        if index < 3 {
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // Custom Progress Bar
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(height: 2)
                        .cornerRadius(3)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.9))
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
    
    func startStatusUpdateTimer() {
        activityTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            updateOrderStatus()
        }
    }
    
    func stopStatusUpdateTimer() {
        // Invalidate the timer when no longer needed
        activityTimer?.invalidate()
        activityTimer = nil
    }
    
    func updateOrderStatus() {
        Task {
            if let activity = activity {
                let currentStatus = activity.content.state.status
                let newStatus = nextStatus(currentStatus)
                let newContentState = OrderWidgetAttributes.ContentState(
                    status: newStatus,
                    estimatedDeliveryTime: activity.content.state.estimatedDeliveryTime
                )
                
                let updatedContent = ActivityContent(state: newContentState, staleDate: nil)
                if #available(iOS 16.2, *) {
                    Task{
                        await activity.update(updatedContent, alertConfiguration: nil)
                    }
                } else  {
                    Task{
                        await  activity.update(using: newContentState)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Not found activity)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func nextStatus(_ currentStatus: OrderStatus) -> OrderStatus {
        let statuses = OrderStatus.allCases
        if let currentIndex = statuses.firstIndex(of: currentStatus) {
            let nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % statuses.count
            let status = statuses[nextIndex]
            if status == .ready {
                stopStatusUpdateTimer()
            }
            return status
        }
        return .ready
    }
    
    func start() {
        guard activity == nil else {return}
        let attr = OrderWidgetAttributes(orderID: UUID())
        let now = Date()
        
        // 10 saniye sonrası için tarihi hesapla
        let tenSecondsLater = now.addingTimeInterval(10)
        
        // ClosedRange<Date> oluştur
        let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = now...tenSecondsLater
        let state = OrderWidgetAttributes.ContentState(status: .inQueue, estimatedDeliveryTime: dateRange)
        let content = ActivityContent(state: state, staleDate: nil)
        do {
            
            self.activity = try Activity<OrderWidgetAttributes>.request(attributes: attr, content: content, pushType: .token)
            startStatusUpdateTimer()
            
            print("ok")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func removeLiveActivity() {
        // Ensure the activity exists
        guard let activity = activity else {
            print("No activity to remove.")
            return
        }
        
        Task {
            await activity.end(activity.content, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
        }
        
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    OrderLiveActivityView()
}

I've done all the requirements, but Live Activity isn't updating. What might I be missing?
